# SPF record validators are reporting my SPF record as wrong - can someone tell me why?

Tags: spf, gmail

If I look at email sent from my small forums server, and received in my private domain Gmail account, the raw headers say:

```
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
   spf=pass
```

So I assumed that meant the SPF record was ok. Over the last few days Gmail has been blocking email from my server to all gmail.com addresses. We aren't on any of the spam lists.

I used some of the online tools to check the validity of the spf record and all the tools say they can't find a valid record when checking the domain, thecoaches.jp.

Mail will be sent from somename@coactivenetwork.thecoaches.jp.

The record I had been using the last year or so was:

```
thecoaches.jp.  IN TXT "v=spf1 mx a a:coactivenetwork.thecoaches.jp ~all"
```

And the new one I created today to replace it is:

```
thecoaches.jp.  IN TXT "v=spf1 mx a ptr ip4:96.126.115.4/32 ~all"
```

I'm using an online SPF record generator to create those records and adding them to a TXT record in the DNS.

Can anybody tell me why the SPF record is invalid?

We only want to send email from the coactivenetwork.thecoaches.jp server. And the IP address shown is the address of that server.

Comment: I've updated my answer below having just reloaded the SPF policy tester against your domain and noticing that you seem to have now amended as per my advice but the record now shows double-quote marks. Best guess is that the DNS record editor you're using is adding quotes for these record types which is also causing problems. I'd recommend removing the quotes.

Comment: stop using PTR, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7208#section-5.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this [SPF policy tester tool](https://vamsoft.com/support/tools/spf-policy-tester) (which I tend to favour as it's nice and verbose), it would appear that your TXT record is incorrect.

It looks like you have some extra text at the beginning of the record:

`thecoaches.jp. IN TXT "v=spf1 mx a ptr ip4:96.126.115.4/32 ~all"`

It should read simply the SPF definition:

`v=spf1 mx a ptr ip4:96.126.115.4/32 ~all`

Basically, it looks like you've appended the text in a format you'd find in a raw zone file, but you're probably using a web ui-based text editor rather than editing the zone file directly (I'm guessing).

EDIT: having just reloaded the policy tester I linked above, it looks like you've done as I initially advised and left the quote marks in, but the policy now returns double quotes - perhaps the DNS record editor you're using adds its own quote marks for these records - I'd recommend trying without.

EDIT2: To answer your question about sending from subdomains - you'll [need to create separate SPF records for all subdomains](http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/The_demon_question). If they're just going to inherit the SPF record for the bare domain I would recommend using something similar to: `v=spf1 include:thecoaches.jp ~all` to simply redirect the SPF lookup to the record for the bare domain.

Comment: Thanks for your info. The tool you mentioned is now showing a pass if the test address is from thecoaches.jp. But the from address will be from coactivenetwork.thecoaches.jp. If I test an address with that domain, the policy tester says no SPF is found. Any ideas?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include subdomains. tl;dr - you need separate SPF records for each subdomain.

Comment: Would my original SPF record I've had for the last year work without the extra text and quote marks: `v=spf1 mx a a:coactivenetwork.thecoaches.jp ~all`

Comment: If you're sending from a subdomain, then no - when the receiving server of the email does the SPF lookup, they'll look up the record for the domain in question - if your sender address is `something@coactivenetwork.thecoaches.jp` then the server will look for a record for `coactivenetwork.thecoaches.jp` - you need to create an SPF record for this subdomain.

Comment: It seems that a test of an address someone@coactivenetwork.thecoaches.jp is now passing the test. There is that warning about the ptr mechanism not being recommended. If I wanted to remove that can I just remove the letters `ptr` from the TXT record?

Comment: That is correct, yes

Comment: It is passing completely now. I don't know if it will fix my Gmail blocking problem, but it did need to be fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Just one final comment (no need to move this to chat). After fixing the SPF records email is again successfully going from my forums server to Gmail.

Comment: Glad to hear it.